# Unix Samba share slow to open from XP machines

Tags: windows-xp, samba, shares

When I open up my samba shares from XP client it can take 10 15 seconds before they become available. What could be causing this. It is a issue that happens most of the time but there are instances where this doesn't happen at all.

Answer (score 1):

you have a dns problem.

Comment: Although not particularly helpful, I fear this answer is correct. Seen it many times, and most delays on network browsing are caused by DNS.

Answer (score 0):

And if it isn't DNS, it could be related to the *LAN Manager Authentication Level* (in the local security policy) set on the XP client. That delay can be caused by negotiations between the client and server having to go back and forth until they find a mutually acceptable protocol. Typically this is more of a problem with older Samba servers that don't have NTLMv2 support.

Answer (score 0):

Try and make an anonymous share and access it from a fresh started client:

```
[anontest]
guest ok = yes
guest only = yes
```

Also, try to access the server using the IP address, like `\\192.168.1.1\share`, to test for DNS/NETBIOS related problems.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://support.microsoft.com/kb/832161

The disabling of the Webclient work around worked for me...

JP